# Android. Вопрос по деактивации разрешений

Tags: android, android-permissions

В общем. В приложении есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую в textview выводится широта и долгота. При нажатии приложение запрашивает разрешения на использование gps, а именно (ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION & ACCES_FINE_LOCATION). Нужно, чтобы после того, как координаты были получены, эти разрешения были деактивированы. И при последующем нажатии на кнопку приложение вновь их запрашивало. Это мое первое приложение на андроид. На работе дали задание разобраться. Прошу помочь.

```
    '''
    btn_getLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // проверка разрешений на доступ к локации
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getLocation();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 56);

            }
        }
    });
    '''
```

Comment: Беглое гугление говорит о невозможности программного отзыва выданных юзером разрешений

Comment: спасибо за информацию!